# grep path as a pattern in afile

Tags: shell, grep

I have a below file

```
cat test.txt 

/mount/u001/oracle/product/12.1.0.2    41004360                                        

/mount/u001/oracle                     7186360
```

I just want to grep exactly "/mount/u001/oracle"

grep -w "/mount/u001/oracle" test.txt gives

```
/mount/u001/oracle/product/12.1.0.2    41004360                                                                        

/mount/u001/oracle                     7186360 


grep "\b/mount/u001/oracle\b" test.txt -- no result                          

grep "^\/mount/u001/oracle\$" test.txt -- no result
```

Comment: See also [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/3266847). Summary: it doesn't matter if it's urgent.

Comment: @all : We have some production issue which has to be addressed

Comment: try `grep '^/mount/u001/oracle '` or `grep '^/mount/u001/oracle[[:blank:]]'`

Comment: Hi Sundeep:Sorry it did not give any result/output ..Thanks for your effort

Answer (score 0):

Wow ..This worked for me

```
  grep "^\/mount/u001/oracle$" test.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Benjamin,Sundeep for Help :-)

Comment: in that case your sample should have included `/mount/u001/oracle` line on its own.. this one could be re-written as `grep -Fx '/mount/u001/oracle'`

Comment: @Sandeep its not working !! Mine also working early and it is not giving the expected result now :-(                                                                                         I am wondering the below not working any suggestions please !!!        
      grep  "^\/mount/u001/oracle$" test.txt